# Drawing cycle by using js oop and svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am getting out of focus when I am practicing the oop and I don't know how to continue.
I have two code and I need to unite the both code.
I need to initialize the variable of svg by using the method of oop.

Need help.
 Thanks.

[link svg:](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_myfirst)

```
    function ArrayMaker(svgcx, svgcy ,svgr ,svgstroke ,svgstroke_width ,svgfill ) {  
    this.svgcx = 100;
    this.svgcy = 50;
    this.svgr = 40;
    this.svgstroke = "red";
    this.svgstroke_width = 3;
    this.svgfill = "yellow";
    this.theArray = [ this, svgcx ,svgcy ,svgr ,svgstroke ,svgstroke_width ,svgfill ];  
}  

ArrayMaker.prototype = {  
    someMethod: function () {  
        alert( 'someMethod called');  
    },  
    getArray: function () {  
        return this.theArray;  
    }  
};  

var am = new ArrayMaker( 'one', 'two' );  
var other = new ArrayMaker( 'first', 'second' );  

alert(am.getArray());
```

this code is work:

```
var cx=100;
var cy=50;
var r=40;
var stroke="red";
var stroke_width=3; 
var fill="yellow";
var htm = "<html>";
htm += "<head>";
htm += "<title>test3</title>";
htm += "</head>";
htm += "<body>";
htm += "<svg ";
htm += " version=";
htm += "\"1.1\"";
htm += ">";
htm += "<circle ";
htm += "cx="+cx+" ";
htm += "cy="+cy+" ";
htm += "r="+r+" ";
htm += "stroke="+stroke+" ";
htm += "stroke-width="+stroke_width+" ";
htm += "fill="+fill+" ";
htm += "/>";

htm += "</body>";
htm += "</html>";
document.write(htm);
```

Answer (score 3):

To create SVG elements with JS you need to use [`createElementNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS) and create elements with the SVG namespace (`http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`). For example, see this demo on my site: http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
function createOn( root, name, attrs ){
  var el = document.createElementNS(svgNS,name);
  for (var attr in attrs){
    if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)) el.setAttribute(attr,attrs[attr]);
  }
  return root.appendChild(el);
}
var svg = createOn( document.body, 'svg', {viewBox:'-100 -100 200 200'} );
createOn( svg, 'circle', { cx:-60, cy:-50, r:20, fill:'#000' });
```

*Note that SVG attributes are not in any namespace, so you can use `setAttribute()` (as I did above) or `setAttributeNS(null,...)`. However, this is not true for attributes specified outside of SVG, like XLink's `href`. For such you need to create the attributes with the correct namespace.*

Comment: Do you have any idea whey the attributes aren't in the svg namespace? I'm a little confused by that.

Comment: @david This is just how XML works. From [Namespaces Crash Course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course): _"By default, attributes don't have a namespace at all, and are only known to be unique because they appear on an element that itself has a unique name."_

Comment: Interesting link, thanks. I find it strange that the attributes don't take the default namespace either then.

Comment: @david See also [Attributes and XML Namespaces](http://www.xmlplease.com/attributexmlns). Given that this is the behavior of XML, it makes sense as to why SVG specified that the attributes were in no namespace; if they put all the attributes in the SVG namespace, you would have to write `<svg xmlns="..." xmlns:svg="..."><circle svg:r="1" svg:cx="10" svg:cy="20" /></svg>`

Comment: I get that now, I just assumed that the `xmlns=` line which sets the default namespace would also apply to attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You should move away from w3schools and document.write. They both represent old ways of doing things.

Phrogz answered before me, but I'll post a link to a jsFiddle you can play with anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/nnjsw/

The code in that link will show you how to properly create a 'circle' object, and how to add a method to the prototype (in this case to move the circles)